# copy a Tabsheet @ run time , read values back after edit process

Tags: delphi

I already found that code to copy several instances of an edit form to a Tpagecontrol

```
var
   aForm : TMyForm;
   tabSheet : TTabSheet;
begin
   //Create a new tab sheet
   tabSheet := TTabSheet.Create(PageControl1) ;
   tabSheet.PageControl := PageControl1;

   //create a form
   aForm := TMyForm.Create(tabSheet) ;
   aForm.Parent := tabSheet;
   aForm.Align := alClient;
   aForm.BorderStyle := bsNone;
   aForm.Visible := true;
   tabSheet.Caption := aForm.Caption;

   //activate the sheet
   PageControl1.ActiveSheet := tabSheet;
end;
```

Assume I run this code 3x , how do i read back the values of any instance of the aForm.button eg. the first page / first instance ?

Comment: You can reduce much of your code using `TControl.ManualDock` http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.ManualDock

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to save an instance of the form. The only way you would be able to do it at the moment would be to search through the controls on the page control.

For example, you could do something like this:

```
function CreateTabAndForm: TMyForm;
var
  tabSheet : TTabSheet;
begin
  //Create a new tab sheet
  tabSheet := TTabSheet.Create(PageControl1) ;
  tabSheet.PageControl := PageControl1;

  //create a form
  Result := TMyForm.Create(tabSheet) ;
  Result.Parent := tabSheet;
  Result.Align := alClient;
  Result.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  Result.Visible := true;
  tabSheet.Caption := Result.Caption;

  //activate the sheet
  PageControl1.ActiveSheet := tabSheet;
end;
```

You need to be careful with this approach, however, as the form could get destroyed if the page control is destroyed.

To create the tabs you would then do something like this:

```
MyForm1 := CreateTabAndForm;
MyForm2 := CreateTabAndForm;
MyForm3 := CreateTabAndForm;
```

To access a button on the form would be MyForm1.button.