# manage an dynamic array of forms (inside a page control)

Tags: delphi

I'm able to create TABSHEETS at run time  using the solution given here [TAB AT RUN TIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21946255/copy-a-tabsheet-run-time-read-values-back-after-edit-process) .
In my use case  I need to create an dynamic number of  forms, I create 3 different subforms on that page control.

How to Create a dynamic set of forms and how to address these controls at run time ?

```
MyForm1 := CreateTabAndForm_type_1;
MyForm2 := CreateTabAndForm_type_1;
MyForm3 := CreateTabAndForm_type_1;
....
???
```

Comment: This question is nothing but a copy/paste of an answer you got from [a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21946426/62576) with `_type_1` appended to every line. You should actually read the answers you get and put some effort into understanding the answers instead of just trying to copy and paste the code. If you had done so, you would have seen **To access a button on the form would be MyForm1.button** in that answer.

Answer (score 2):

Create a record containing a tabsheet and a form:

```
type 
  TTabsheetAndForm = record
    Tabsheet: TTabsheet;
    Form: TMyForm;
  end;
```

Then use either a dynamic array: `TArray<TTabsheetAndForm>` or `array of TTabsheetAndForm`. Or a generic container: `TList<TTabsheetAndForm>`.

Then populate the array or list as you instantiate your GUI controls.

If there are always exactly three of these things as you hint, then perhaps you don't even need the array. Three variables will do the job.

Comment: Just be careful with a generic container of records. You should consider them WORM. When you iterate over the items to modify them, you're only modifying copies. That's why i keep using classes for these containers. I hope that ARC will come to windows too, so that we don't have to pollute our code with irrelevant memory management stuff.

Comment: @Wouter I sometimes use a generic container whose iterator returns pointers to the elements.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small sample how to add a form to a PageControl and how to get the form instance back from the TabSheet.

- forms are docked to the PageControl with `TControl.ManualDock`
- so docked forms are accessible through `TTabSheet.Controls[0]` (the form is the first control on this TabSheet)

---

**This sample is just a POC and did not cover all the checking you will do in a real application.**

---

### The MainForm

```
type
  TMainForm = class( TForm )
    PageControl1 : TPageControl;
    Button_Panel : TPanel;
    AddForm_Button : TButton;
    PressButtonOnSubForm_Button: TButton;
    procedure AddForm_ButtonClick( Sender : TObject );
    procedure PressButtonOnSubForm_ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    function CreateFormInPageControl( AFormClass : TFormClass; APageControl : TPageControl ) : TForm;
    function GetFormFromTabSheet( ATabSheet : TTabSheet ) : TForm;
    function GetActivePageControlForm( APageControl : TPageControl ) : TForm;
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

implementation

uses
  FormSub;

procedure TMainForm.PressButtonOnSubForm_ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // push the button
  if Assigned( PageControl1.ActivePage ) then
    ( GetActivePageControlForm(PageControl1) as TSubForm ).Button1.Click;
end;

procedure TMainForm.AddForm_ButtonClick( Sender : TObject );
var
  LForm : TForm;
begin
  LForm := CreateFormInPageControl( TSubForm, PageControl1 );
end;

function TMainForm.CreateFormInPageControl( AFormClass : TFormClass; APageControl : TPageControl ) : TForm;
begin
  // create a new form from the given form class
  Result := AFormClass.Create( Self );
  // dock the form to the give page control
  Result.ManualDock( APageControl, nil, alClient );
  // show the form
  Result.Show;
end;

function TMainForm.GetActivePageControlForm( APageControl : TPageControl ) : TForm;
begin
  Result := GetFormFromTabSheet( APageControl.ActivePage );
end;

function TMainForm.GetFormFromTabSheet( ATabSheet : TTabSheet ) : TForm;
begin
  Result := ATabSheet.Controls[0] as TForm;
end;
```

---

### The SubForm

```
type
  TSubForm = class( TForm )
    Button1 : TButton;
    ListBox1 : TListBox;
    procedure Button1Click( Sender : TObject );
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

procedure TSubForm.Button1Click( Sender : TObject );
begin
  // just to put some action to this form
  ListBox1.ItemIndex := ListBox1.Items.Add( 'Button pressed' );
end;
```

---

### Update

If you want to get rid of a docked form you simply call (for the current active form)

```
GetActivePageControlForm( PageControl1 ).Release;
```

The TabSheet will disappear then too.