# dynamically placing forms on a pagecontrol

Tags: delphi

as an extension of my previous post [forms an a pagecontrol at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21950985/manage-an-dynamic-array-of-forms-inside-a-page-control) 
I need a solution how to pass a buttonclick event back to the parent pagecontrol.
Do I have a assign a click function as a property and assign a new click function to all my forms for all the buttons i have placed :-( ....   much work , any better solution

```
MyMainForm = CLass( )
....
aPagecontrol  : TPageControl;
aTabForm_1  : TTabForm_1 ;  //  in the real case I use an dynamic array 
aTabForm_2  : TTabForm_2 ;
aTabForm_3  : TTabForm_3 ;

....
UserData  : TUserdata ;   //  lot of user data ....


function MyMainForm.CreateTabAndForm:  TTabForm_1;
 var
 tabSheet : TTabSheet;
 begin
 //Create a new tab sheet
 tabSheet := TTabSheet.Create(PageControl1) ;
 tabSheet.PageControl := PageControl1;

 //create a form
 Result :=  TTabForm_1.Create(tabSheet) ;
 Result.Parent := tabSheet;
 Result.Align := alClient;
 Result.BorderStyle := bsNone;
 Result.Visible := true;
 tabSheet.Caption := Result.Caption;

  //activate the sheet
PageControl1.ActiveSheet := tabSheet;
end;





//  program code , now failing :  

 aTabForm_1 :=  CreateTabAndForm;
 aTabForm_1.onclick := MyButtonOnclick; //  here AV happens !!

....
end;
```

the definition of the form

```
//  
TTabForm_1 = class(TForm)
...


property clickButton1 : TClickfunction .......
end;
```

- Solution #1  -> pass all the data to TTabForm_1 using properties
- Solution #2  -> pass Button Click event to Mainform

target : readable code - good design

Comment: You should tell what is your final goal ... it is not very wise to perform a button click. A click on a button is for the user and telling your application what kind of **action** the user want to perform. So start the action and do not press the button

Comment: As Sir Rufo has said, we need to know what the structure of your application is and what it's trying to do. Why exactly do you need a button click to have an effect on its containing pagecontrol?

Comment: now better?  showing more code to discuss .... ?

Comment: @Andy_D it's a pretty common design pattern to have UI elements segregated from business logic.  Nested controls need a way to bubble up events to whatever object *is* in control of the business logic.  It's not that the child control needs to do anything with its parent control, it simply needs to notify the parent that an event has occured.

Comment: @J I'm fully aware of that, it's just the question is rather vague in specifics which makes it difficult to come up with an answer. The obvious solution is to implement some kind of Model-GUI-Mediator design which would allow the "outer" form to observe the business object and react to changes made to the business object in the "inner" form.

Comment: What should be done in that callback event? Updating data?

Answer (score 3):

One way to expose events raised inside a form or control is like this :

```
unit Unit2;

interface    
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;    
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FButton1Clicked : TNotifyEvent; //Create a private TNotifyEvent field
  public
    // ...and expose it as a property
    property OnButton1Click : TNotifyEvent read FButton1Clicked
                                           write FButton1Clicked;
  end;

implementation    
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Execute the method if it has been assigned when Button1 is clicked.
  if Assigned(FButton1Clicked) then FButton1Clicked(Sender);
end;

end.
```

Which you would consume like :

```
unit Unit1; 

interface    
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Unit2;    
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FForm2 : TForm2;
    procedure Form2ButtonClick(sender : TObject);//Create a TNotifyEvent handler
  end;    
var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation    
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FForm2 := TForm2.Create(self);
  //Assign a method to your custom event property
  FForm2.OnButton1Click := Form2ButtonClick; 
  FForm2.Show;
end;

procedure TForm1.Form2ButtonClick(sender: TObject);
begin
  // Do Something...
end;

end.
```

Of course, you don't have to use a `TNotifyEvent`, you can create any custom event, with parameters, that you like.  For example

```
type
  TFooEvent = procedure(ANumber : double; Sender : TObject) of object;
```

Which you could then use to send data with the click event :

```
if Assigned(FButton1Clicked) then FButton1Clicked(1.23, Button1);
```

Comment: following this answer I get an AV at the the code line :  FForm2.OnButton1Click := Form2ButtonClick; I my version I first run the form2.show and later in the code sequence I assign FForm2.OnButton1Click := Form2ButtonClick;

Comment: @Franz Did you write `Form2` instead of `FForm2`, perhaps?  Should always get rid of the default globals that Delphi creates.

Comment: the code sequence is now part of the question , I follow the instructions above

Comment: @Franz I'm afraid I can't offer much advice with only bits and pieces of your code.  I assure you that the code above works, so something you have done (somewhere in code you have not shown us) is not correct.

Comment: understand will do the bug search on my own ...  anyhow thanks for the help , solution itself seem to be fine