# delete tabs from a page control at run time

Tags: delphi

according to the previous question [TABS @ RUN TIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21946255/copy-a-tabsheet-run-time-read-values-back-after-edit-process) I create tabsheets at run time.
Now I suffer the problem deleting tabs at run time, my solution for the inverse function goes like this

```
procedure TForm.DeleteAllTabs(sender : TObject);
var  i  : Integer;
begin
    for I := 0  to  pagecontrol1.PageCount-1 do
    pagecontrol1.Pages[i].Destroy
end;
```

but it claims that the i is out of bound ..... (access violation)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When 'i' is initially '0' you're deleting `Pages[0]` and the remaining sheets are moved one position down. That is after the deletion, the first sheet is still at `Pages[0]`. But in the next iteration you're deleting `Pages[1]` skipping the first page. When eventually you try to delete a non-existing page, you get the error.

Step by step, let's say at first you have three sheets,

> [page0] [page1] [page2]

The index counter is '0', you delete `Pages[0]`, the remaining two sheets are moved to the start,

> [page0] [page1]

The index counter is '1', you delete the second page, that's `Pages[1]`. There's only one remaining page,

> [page0]

The index counter is '2', you delete the third page, that's `Pages[2]`. There's no `Pages[2]`, you get error.

One solution is to always delete the first page:

```
 for I := 0  to  pagecontrol1.PageCount-1 do
 pagecontrol1.Pages[0].Free;
```

Another one can be starting to delete from the last page as stated in TLama's comment.

```
 for I := pagecontrol1.PageCount-1 downto 0 do
 pagecontrol1.Pages[i].Free;
```